# YQL - No definition found for Table

Tags: python, yql, yahoo-finance

My code:

```
import yql
y = yql.Public()
query = 'SELECT * FROM yahoo.finance.option_contracts WHERE symbol="SPY"'
y.execute(query)
```

Result:

```
yql.YQLError: No definition found for Table yahoo.finance.option_contracts
```

I know that the table exists because I can test the query at http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/ and it works. What am I missing?

Update: I posted the url to the console but not the query I tried in the console. The query is now attached.

```
http://goo.gl/mNXwC
```

Comment: Nope.. It says definition not found even in the link you are specifying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `yahoo.finance.option_contracts` table is a [Community Open Data Table](http://datatables.org) you will want to include it as part of the environment for the query. The easiest way to do that is to load up the environment file for *all* community tables; just like clicking "Show Community Tables" in the YQL console.

One would normally do that by specifying an `env=...` parameter in the YQL query URL, or (as you have done) with a `use` clause in the query itself.

The Python library that you are using lets you pass in the environment file as an argument to `execute()`.

```
import yql
y = yql.Public()
query = 'SELECT * FROM yahoo.finance.option_contracts WHERE symbol="SPY"'
y.execute(query, env="store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys")
```

---

Here's an example of extending `yql.Public` to be able to define the default environment on instantiation.

```
class MyYql(yql.Public):

    def __init__(self, api_key=None, shared_secret=None, httplib2_inst=None, env=None):
        super(MyYql, self).__init__(api_key, shared_secret, httplib2_inst)
        self.env = env if env else None

    def execute(self, query, params=None, **kwargs):
        kwargs["env"] = kwargs.get("env", self.env)
        return super(MyYql, self).execute(query, params, **kwargs);
```

It can be used like:

```
y = MyYql(env="store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys")
query = 'SELECT * FROM yahoo.finance.option_contracts WHERE symbol="SPY"'
r = y.execute(query)
```

You can still override the `env` in an individual call to `y.execute()` if you need to.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to provide the env as part of initializing instead of having to pass it with every execute()?

Comment: No, but it's not a huge amount of work to extend `yql.Public` to do that. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Amending query to the following is what works.

> query = 'use "http://www.datatables.org/yahoo/finance/yahoo.finance.option_contracts.xml" as foo; SELECT * FROM foo WHERE symbol="SPY"'

More elegant solutions might exist. Please share if such do. Thanks.